# OpenSUSE firewall services map

Tags: opensuse, services, firewalld

How are services mapped to ports in firewalld on openSUSE? I would have expected /etc/services. I saw this was recently moved to /usr/etc/services, but that doesn't seem to be the place either.

Specifically, I'm trying to get KDE Connect to work on openSUSE Tumbleweed. I'm sure opening the ports will work, but there are two defined services, `kdeconnect` and `kdeconnect-kde`, and I'm trying to figure out why enabling these in the right zone is not working. /usr/etc/services definitely lists services, but nothing for kdeconnect.

Edit: Weirdly, KDE Connect just decided to start working, but I'm still curious about the services thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/usr/lib/firewalld/services/
```

```
ls -l /usr/lib/firewalld/services/ | head -1
total 700
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeBuckley Found with `rpm -ql firewalld` BTW.

Comment: Ah, and I use that to find config files and binaries all the time, but it didn't cross my mind here.